# vuejs Model for radio list item

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

How to set a v-model for a framework7-vue radio list item element?

[Checkboxes & Radios Vue Component](https://framework7.io/vue/checkboxes-radios.html)

```
  <f7-list-item 
    radio 
    name="my-radio" 
    v-model="method.val" 
    value="ISNA" 
    title="Islamic Society of North America" 
    subtitle="ISNA" 
    text="North America (US and Canada)">
  </f7-list-item>
```

the above code does not work.

Comment: Do you have an error? `method.val` must be defined as a boolean in your component data

Comment: There also appears to be a space in the "radio name" attribute.

Comment: @NathanWailes the space is intended, and *should* be name on a new line, if following the rest of his code convention

Answer (score 2):

The problem is an issue of undocumented features, as per [this github exchange](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Framework7-Vue/issues/99)

You can fix it by adding an `input-value` attribute to the f7-list-item, as follows:

```
<f7-list-item 
  radio 
  name="my-radio" 
  v-model="method.val" 
  value="ISNA"
  input-value="ISNA"
  title="Islamic Society of North America" 
  subtitle="ISNA" 
  text="North America (US and Canada)">
</f7-list-item>
```

Remember, however, these caveats:

> input-value can not be empty string. From list-item.vue, `valueComputed` fallbacks to `this.value` if `this.inputValue` is empty.

However, that fallback appears to not be working, since, like you said (and I experienced as well), it doesn't update the `v-model` if no input-value is added. So TLDR; make sure input-value isn't an empty string, or things will break.

Comment: let me check this

Answer (score 2):

@mix3d's answer works well for radio buttons, but since the docs are lacking on this topic I'm going to be explicit and add this example as well.  For a checkbox list-item, set `input-value` to your favorite boolean as a string and use `v-model` to bind it to a corresponding javascript boolean in your `data`:

```
<template>
    <f7-list form>
        <f7-list-item checkbox name="friends" input-value="true" title="Friends" v-model="settings.friends"></f7-list-item>
    </f7-list>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                settings: {
                    friends: true
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```